# JQuery AJAX Call reports success in every browser but Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, jquery

I'm working on a bit of legacy code that is being used to authenticate users to a web application via username/password check. The code is contained within a standard ASPX page (yes, I know) and, when the page is requested it either returns status 404 to indicate an authentication failure or populates a literal on the ASPX page if all is well.

Its a standard JQuery `ajax` call:

```
    $("#btnSWSignInPin").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Security/Validate.aspx",
        type: "GET",
        data: "Rnd=" + Math.random() + "&Identifier=" + $(".inpIdentifier").val() + "&Pin=" + $("#inpSWPin").val(),
        success: function () {
            $("#divSessionLogin").jqmHide();
            WarnInFuture();
            DoChecks = true;
        },
        error: function () {
            ShowLogin("The password you entered was incorrect. Please try again.");
        }
    });
    $("#inpSWPin").val("");

    return false;
});
```

The .NET code which this calls runs fine and I can successfully step through it with no issues in VS. I have tested extensively in Safari, Firefox and IE9, all but the latter on OSX and Windows, and it executes as expected. However in Chrome (latest build) the success function is never executed, the javascript seems to think that something other than status 200 is being returned from the browser although `Fiddler` shows its definitely a 200 in the Response header.

Can anyone suggest what I can check to try to understand and correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a url parsing problem, please try by giving your parameters this way :

```
data = {
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": false,
    "key_4": 123
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is working perfectly in all but Chrome - does Chrome require things to be done differently?

Comment: No, Google Chrome is generally the more compatible browser so it's astonishing. Just a little advice : try to use only lower-case names when working with URLs

Comment: That's my general opinion of Chrome which is why this is all the more perplexing.

Answer (score 0):

Set

async: false

Google Chrome seems to have an issue with firing success when async is set to true.